# Pegar o value de um select e jogar em variável php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cakephp-2

Como faço para pegar o valor selecionado de um select e já imprimir ele?
Eu tenho um formulário simples, quando o usuário selecionar o valor quero atribuir a uma variável php, porque vou mostrar a quantidade selecionada e quantidade selecionada x o valor do ingresso selecionado.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="cb_catinsumo" class="form-control   select_ticket" name="teste">
      <option value="0">0</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Como faço para pegar o valor selecionado de um select e já imprimir
>   ele?

Para isso você precisa de um javascript (jQuery é mais simples):

```js
$(document).ready( function ()
{
 $("#cb_catinsumo").on('change', function() {
  var option = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    $('#res').html("Opcao selecionada: "+option);
 });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="cb_catinsumo" class="form-control   select_ticket" name="teste">
      <option value="0">0</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div id='res'></div>
```

Se quiser utilizar com algum trecho de php, sugiro que faça um Ajax. Php é uma linguagem server side, ou seja, roda no servidor e envia os resultados ao cliente, já o javascript é client side, sendo assim roda no lado do cliente, portanto para atribuir ou manipular os valores, faça uma requisição ajax.

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda, tem algum link que mostre esse tipo de requisição para mim ter uma base de como fazer isso?

Comment: Pode encontrar varios exemplo aqui mesmo no Stack: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o+ajax ou até mesmo lendo na documentação do jQuery, ou na w3school https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_examples.asp

Answer (score 1):

Cara, encima da sua dúvida vou tentar lhe dar uma solução sem precisar jogar na variável PHP. O código jQuery para isso seria simples:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     
     $(document).on('click', '#vervalor', function(){
    
      let valor_ingresso = $('#cb_ingresso option:selected').val();
      let quantidade_ingresso = $('#cb_catinsumo option:selected').val();
      let total = (valor_ingresso*quantidade_ingresso);
    
      $('.total').css('display', 'block');
      $('#preco_total').html('R$ '+total);
     });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="cb_ingresso" class="form-control   select_ticket" name="teste1">
      <option value="0">Selecione o tipo de ingresso</option>
      <option value="50.00">Inteira</option>
      <option value="25.00">Meia</option>
      <option value="25.00">Lote Promocional</option>
      <option value="100.00">Camarote</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="cb_catinsumo" class="form-control   select_ticket" name="teste2">
      <option value="0">Selecione a quantidade de ingresso</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<button type="button" id="vervalor">Visualizar Valor Total</button>

<div class="total" style="display:none">
    Preço Total: <span id="preco_total"></span>
</div>
```

> Caso você precise buscar o preço no banco de dados e não fazer o
>   select como fiz o primeiro, então use a função $.ajax() do jQuery por
>   exemplo.